# What are some verses from upanishad that say God is all powerful or omnipotent?

Tags: upanishads

What are some verses that clearly say God is all powerful from upanishad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are some verses from upanishad that say God is all powerful or omnipotent?

**[Taittiriya Upanishad](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/index.htm)**

Ananda Valli of Taittiriya Upanishad shows that Brahman is creator of all:

> He wished, may I be many, may I grow forth. He brooded over himself. After he had thus brooded, he created all, whatever there is. Having created all, he entered into them. Having entered them, he became sat the existent and the non-existent, defined and undefined, supported and not supported, with knowledge and without knowledge, real and unreal. The Sattya became all this whatsoever, and therefore the wise call him Sat-tya.

Next verse describes Brahman as existing before creation:

> In the beginning this was non-manifset. From it was born what exists.

Next section describes Brahman as being the over-lord of the Devas:

> From fear of him (Brahman) the wind (Vayu) blows, from terror the Sun rises; from terror of it Agni and Indra, and Death (Mrtyu) runs as the fifth.

Brahman is so powerful, that his bliss surpasses the bliss of all the Devas combined:

> One hundred times that bliss of Pragâpati (lord BrahmA) is one measure of the bliss of Brahman.

**[Kaushitaki Upanishad](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01241.htm)**

Brahman punishes and rewards people as per their karma:

> For he (Brahman) makes him, whom he wishes to lead up from these worlds, do a good deed; and the same makes him, whom he wishes to lead down from these worlds, do a bad deed.

He is the Lord of the world:

> He is the guardian of the world, he is the king of the world, he is the lord of the universe.

**[Chandogya Upanishad](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01048.htm)**

Whatever he thinks, that will happen:

> whose thoughts are true

And many more verses.